# how to create responsive slantedDiv?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

[I want something like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNmsp.png)

```css
.slantedDiv
{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height:500px;
 background: #C57ED3;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding:30px;
 color:#fff;
}
.slantedDiv:after
{ position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
content: '';
background:red ;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
transform-origin: top left;
transform: skewY(4deg);

}
#image {
   
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slantedDiv" id="image" >
   hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
</div>
```

hello, actually I wanted to create a responsive slanted div and add paragraph or something on the div. but i try all possible things but it remains same as per the output.paragraphs as usually behind the div ,it not showing .please help me out. 
Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: please add a screenshot of what you're expecting. thanks

Comment: please look at my answer i will be help to you.i have used z-index to avoid it.

Comment: no issues bro . we are here to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have used z-index to solve this issue please look at the code.

```css
.slantedDiv
{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height:500px;
 background: #C57ED3;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding:30px;
 color:#fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
.slantedDiv:after
{ position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
content: '';
background:red;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
transform-origin: top left;
transform: skewY(4deg);
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slantedDiv" id="image" >
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
</div>
```